# How do I migrate over to another exchange server?

Tags: windows-server-2003, email, exchange

I have two servers (Exchanger 2003) listed under Exchange Server and only want to have one (very small company ~50 users 2nd one was brought in as an upgrade). The second was added to become the primary by the last IT guy but the migration was never finished. I have limited Exchange experience but can definitely follow instructions if anyone has a walkthrough or can point me in the right direction.

short version: I need to migrate Exchange from one server to another (all mailboxes, etc.).

This includes OWA, and I need the address the users go to mail.companyname.com/exchange to remain the same. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You might want to get in touch with a consulting company to help you.

Comment: +1 to Joe Doyle's comment. If you don't know how to do this, call in an expert. Users tend to get upset when their mailboxes don't work (or exist...)

Answer (score 1):

There is a write up here for how to do it, but obviously it is a fairly involved task.

http://www.amset.info/exchange/migration.asp

I think this quote from that article is important to take seriously:

> "If after reading this guide it raises more questions than it answers, then it isn't for you."